# Simulating different data with decorators in python

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to force myself to understand how decorators work and how I might use them to run a function multiple times.

I am trying to simulate datasets with three variables, but they vary on their sample size and whether the sampling was conditional or not.

So I create the population distribution that I am sampling from:

```
from numpy.random import normal, negative_binomial, binomial
import pandas as pd

population_N = 100000
data = pd.DataFrame({ 
    "Variable A": normal(0, 1, population_N),
    "Variable B": negative_binomial(1, 0.5, population_N),
    "Variable C": binomial(1, 0.5, population_N)
})
```

Rather than doing the following:

```
sample_20 = data.sample(20)
sample_50 = data.sample(50)

condition = data["Variable B"] != 0

sample_20_non_random = data[condition].sample(20)
sample_50_non_random = data[condition].sample(50)
```

I wanted to simplify things and make it more efficient. So I started with a super simple function where I can pass whether or not the sample will be random or not.

```
def simple_function(data_frame, type = "random"):
    if (type == "random"):
        sample = data_frame.sample(sample_size)
    else:
        condition = data_frame["Variable B"] != 0
        sample = data_frame[condition].sample(sample_size)
    return sample
```

But, I want to do this for more than one sample size. So I thought that rather than writing a for-loop that can be slow, I could maybe just use a decorator. I also have tried but have failed to understand their logic, so I thought this could be good practice to try to understand them better.

```
import functools

def decorator(cache = {}, **case):
    def inner(function):
        function_name = function.__name__
        if function_name not in cache:
            cache[function_name] = function
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapped_function(**kwargs):
            if cache[function_name] != function:
                cache[function_name](**case)
            else:
                function(**case)
        return wrapped_function
    return inner

@decorator(sample_size = [20, 50])
def sample(data_frame, type = "random"):
    if (type == "random"):
        sample = data_frame.sample(sample_size)
    else:
        condition = data_frame["Variable B"] != 0
        sample = data_frame[condition].sample(sample_size)
    return sample
```

I guess what I am not understanding is how the inheritance of the arguments works and how that then affects the iteration over the function in the decorator.

Comment: What's the problem with adding `sample_size` as parameter to `simple_function`? I don't quite understand yet how a decorator can help you here.

Comment: I guess, I am trying to avoid writing a for-loop in the `simple_function` and thought that a decorator could be a possible alternative. If a decorator would be inappropriate, would you have a recommendation?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in my comment.

Comment: If you're trying to cache results, there's already `@functools.cache`

Comment: If you want to do something multiple times in a particular function, use a for loop in that function.  A decorator is for when you want to apply the same type of modification to a bunch of different functions.  It rarely ever makes sense to write a decorator that you are only going to apply to one specific function.